# How do I improve this Stored Procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a question:

Assuming an assembly line where a bike goes through  some tests, and then the devices send the information regarding the test to 
our database (in oracle). I created this stored procedure; it works correctly for what I want, which is:

It gets a list of the first test (per type of test) that a bike has gone through. For instance, if a bike had 2 tests of the same type, it only 
shows the first one, AND it shows it only when that first test is between the dates specified by the user. Also I look from 2 months back 
because a bike cannot spend more than 2 months (I'm probably overestimating) at the assembly line, but if the user searches 2 days for instance, and I only look in between those days, I could let outside of my results a test made over a bike 3 days ago or maybe 4, and it get's worst if they search between hours.
As I said before, the sp works just fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize it.
Also consider that the table has around 7 millions of records by the end of the year, so I cannot query the whole year because it could get ugly.

Here's the main part of the stored procedure:

```
SELECT pid                                AS "bike_id",             
         TYPE                               AS "type",
         stationnr                          AS "stationnr",
         testtime                           AS "testtime",
         rel2.releasenr                     AS "releasenr",
         placedesc                          AS description,
         tv.recordtime                      AS "recordtime",
         To_char(tv.testtime, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS "dategroup",
         testcounts                         AS "testcounts",
         tv.result                          AS "result",
         progressive                        AS "PROGRESIVO"
  FROM   (SELECT l_bike_id                                        AS pid,
                 l_testcounts                                 AS testcounts,
                 To_char(l_testtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS testtimes,
                 testtime,
                 pl.code                                      AS place,                     
                 t2.recordtime,
                 t2.releaseid,
                 t2.testresid,                     
                 t2.stationnr,
                 t2.result,                                          
                 v.TYPE,
                 v.progressive,
                 v.prs,
                 pl.description                               AS placeDesc
          FROM   (SELECT v.bike_id             AS l_bike_id,
                         v.TYPE            AS l_type,
                         Min(t.testtime)   AS l_testtime,
                         Count(t.testtime) AS l_testcounts
                  FROM   result_test t
                         inner join bikes v
                                 ON v.bike_id = t.pid
                         inner join result_release rel
                                 ON t.releaseid = rel.releaseid
                         inner join resultconfig.places p
                                 ON p.place = t.place
                  WHERE  t.testtime >= Add_months(Trunc(p_startdate), -2)
                  GROUP  BY v.bike_id,
                            v.TYPE,
                            p.code)p_bikelist
                 inner join result_test t2
                         ON p_bikelist.l_bike_id = t2.pid
                            AND p_bikelist.l_testtime = t2.testtime
                 inner join resultconfig.places pl
                         ON pl.place = t2.place
                 inner join bikes v
                         ON v.bike_id = t2.pid
                 inner join result_release rel2
                         ON t2.releaseid = rel2.releaseid
          ORDER  BY t2.pid)tv
         inner join result_release rel2
                 ON tv.releaseid = rel2.releaseid
  WHERE   tv.testtime BETWEEN p_startdate AND p_enddate             
  ORDER  BY testtime;
```

Thank you for answering!!

Comment: `ORDER BY` in subuery does not change anything

Comment: Read about windowing functions -- e.g., `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v.bike_id ORDER BY t.test_time)`.  Put that in an inner query, give it an alias like `rown` and then, in the outer query, add `WHERE rown = 1` to get the first test for each bike.  This eliminates a lot of the redundant joins you have in your post.  There are a many examples on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling a bit to understand the business requirement from the English description you give. The wording suggests that this procedure is intended to work **per bike** but I don't see any obvious bike_id parameters being supplied, instead, you appear to be returning the earliest result for **all** bikes tested between given dates. Is that the aim? If it is designed to be run per bike, then ensure bike id gets passed in and used early :)

There is some confusion about your data types. You convert testtime in result_test (presumably a DATE or TIMESTAMP column ) into a string in the p_bikelist subquery but then compare back to the original value in the tv subquery. You further use (presumably typed parameters) p_startdate and p_enddate to filter results. I strongly suspect the conversion in p_bikelist to be unnecessary, and possibly a cause for index avoidance.

Finally, I don't get the add_months logic. By all means, extend the window back in time to get tests that **finished** within the window but started up to 2 months before the start date, but as written you will exclude the earlier starts anyway because of the condition on tv.testtime. Most likely you'd be better off fudging the startdate earlier in the stored procedure with code like

```
l_assumedstart := add_months(p_startdate, -2);
```

and then using l_assumedstart in the query itself.